# Is there a word or a common phrase for this motion of the hands

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to describe this motion with words. What would be the concise way?

(Actually it's this motion but with the hands closer to the lap than the face but that's not very important)

[image]

Comment: When done near the face like this, it has a connotation of dark contemplation. (scheming) If done near the lap, I'm not sure. I'd have to see it on context. It might have a different meaning.

Comment: Somewhat tangental, but another scheming gesture is "dry washing" - rubbing one's hands together, as a villain would do while saying "it's all going to plan…"

Comment: I think I've heard the phrase "tented his hands".

Comment: I can't decide if that's Peter Dinklage or the bad guy from Superman II...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Steepled** is the term.

It is more widely understood as "**[steepled fingers](http://space-bridge-to-nowhere.tumblr.com/post/28508050295/not-truly-a-villain)**" rather than "**[steepled hands](http://nysac.org/news/nysac-news-winter-2013/power-gestures-friend-or-foe/)**" though.

Comment: I've always called it "Mr Burns hands", after the Simpsons character. Now that I know there's a proper word for it, I'm not sure I want to abandon my reference :(

Comment: Hello, @Polynomial It is nice to see you around here! Mr. Burns was #3 in Google image search for steepled hands  ;O)

Comment: This is the right term. See body language project for more info on why this is not a rapport-building thing to dk with others

Comment: I’ve never heard “steepled” and have only heard “tented” for this. I suspect region may be a factor. I’m writing from a predominantly AmE background.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung The source for my 2nd link is the New York State Association of Counties (definitely AmE ;O).

Comment: @Ellie It could even be regional within the US! They say _on_ line out there when people are in line for something, for one thing

Comment: **Templed** is also used, though less frequently: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22templed+his+fingers%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 15):

**Tented hands** or **tented fingers**.

[Here is a Slate.com blog post](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/03/24/muppets_most_wanted_when_did_finger_tenting_or_steepling_become_a_symbol.html) with this caption and image:

[image]

> How did finger-tenting become a symbol of evil?

Answer (score 0):

David Foster Wallace calls this making hand cages, or pyramids, or shapes in "[Brief Interviews with Hideous Men](https://books.google.com/books?id=EC-10nIgKIkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Brief+Interviews+with+Hideous+Men%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBivXS8L73AhXyNX0KHf2EB0EQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=snippet&q=shapes%20cage&f=false)" in the context of a woman visiting her therapist.

Comment: Many authors might have described it in their own words. Comparing it with familiar shapes makes for an easy interpretation of the phrase, but that doesn't mean it's common.